# How to extract property and value from string

Tags: css, string, variables, sass, properties

I have a string containing a "normal css line" (a property name, a colon, a value and a semicolon). And I want to just copy that to my output css. Like this:

```
$str: "background: red;";
.red {
    // Just write $str
}

// =============>

.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Here is what I tested:

```
$str: "background: red;";
.red {
    $str; // error
    $str // error
    #{$str}; // error
    #{$str} // error
    string.unquote($str); // error
    string.unquote($str) // error
    #{string.unquote($str)}; // error
    #{string.unquote($str)} // error
}
```

I think that I can do it by spliting string, or something similar...

But I want to know the best/simplest way.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have no idea and can't help you. Is there any reason not to use `@mixin`? For example, To define `@mixin bgr{ background: red; }`. To use `@include bgr;`

Comment: @Miu, In fact, I have a large map of strings and I can't convert them all to mixins... however, I can use javascript or something similar to convert them. But I want to know if there is a way to do that with just strings...